# Issues about inlcuding external javascript files & css via https

Tags: javascript, https, stylesheet

Our website uses party https and http protocols.
But the is the problem, that the browser has to load the css & js files twice (first time http:/....tld/style.css and second time https:/....tld/style.css).

I thought about including these files always absolutly as https:/....tld/style.css .

Are any concerns about this proposition (e.g. the ssl encrypting performance?).

I haven't seen this proposition at any other websites, so I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: See [protocol-relative URL](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

Answer (score 0):

Via SSL you will receive the same file but encrypted that means it's bigger and slower. It depends on the SSL key which is used on the server, however it could twice the size of the data at least, I guess.